# NumberFormatException when Persisting to Mongo Database

Tags: java, exception, morphia

I am creating a simple `VO` object and then trying to persist it into Mongo Database am getting `NumberFormatException` worst part is that exception is not being thrown from object itself as right now am not setting any properties of the object, this exception is killing me and am not sure how to deal it.

Here is the piece of code that is throwing exception:

```
public void testAgenda(){
    ItemVO item = new ItemVO();
    try {
        item.persist();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getCause();
        e.getMessage();
    }
```

Here is the exception strace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4e3c3da5fbb7d7b41ce9e394"
        at com.google.code.morphia.mapping.Mapper.updateKeyInfo(Mapper.java:194)
        at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.postSaveOperations(DatastoreImpl.java:742)
        at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:645)
        at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:685)
        at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:679)
        at com.williamblair.im.research.domain.vo.BaseDocument.persist(BaseDocument.java:68)
        at com.williamblair.im.research.service.TestListService.testGetResearchAgenda_aroundBody2(TestListService.java:31)
        at com.williamblair.im.research.service.TestListService$AjcClosure3.run(TestListService.java:1)
        at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149)
        at com.williamblair.im.research.system.aop.profiling.ProfilingAspect.doProfiling(ProfilingAspect.java:36)
        at com.williamblair.im.research.service.TestListService.testGetResearchAgenda(TestListService.java:26)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
    Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4e3c3da5fbb7d7b41ce9e394"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:419)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:468)
        at com.google.code.morphia.converters.LongConverter.decode(LongConverter.java:22)
        at com.google.code.morphia.converters.TypeConverter.decode(TypeConverter.java:45)
        at com.google.code.morphia.converters.DefaultConverters.decode(DefaultConverters.java:144)
        at com.google.code.morphia.mapping.Mapper.setIdValue(Mapper.java:390)
        at com.google.code.morphia.mapping.Mapper.updateKeyInfo(Mapper.java:174)
        ... 39 more
```

I have been debugging this issue for a while now and have not found the starting point yet, any suggestions?

Here is the persist method:

```
public void persist() {
this.morphiaDatastore.save(this);
}
```

**Update**

```
public class ItemVO {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private double marketCap;
    private Long analystId;

    private Date dateAdded;

    private boolean onResearch;

}
```

Comment: I have no idea about the Mongo/Morphia part, but you seem to be trying to persist a `String` field which holds a hexstring in a database column which can only hold numerical values. Hex or not, strings are not numbers.

Comment: Can you post the `ItemVO` class definition? I would like to see all the fields, methods and annotations.

Comment: @BalusC - can you elaborate more on your explanation.

Comment: Looks like you're generating a different kind of Key than is expected.

Comment: @BalusC - He is using MongoDB, a document store; there is no such things as 'columns' or datatypes.

Comment: @Gweebz - updated with ItemVO description

Comment: You are using the wrong type for your @Id type, see Scotts answer for all the details on how to fix your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use a Long value then you need to assign the id field before saving!

If you want to use autogenerated identifiers, use ObjectId type in the id field.

If you don't set the Long value for the @Id field then the server will create an ObjectId for the field, and it is not compatible with the Long datatype declared in your class. So when you read the document/entity it will complain about the data type conversion error.

Comment: I've edited Scott's answer to give you more details on using the `ObjectId` type for your `@Id` field.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem as though `this` is not something that can be converted to a number. From the look of the Stacktrace it's because it's in Hex and whatever is converting it is looking for decimal. Do you know what it's attempting to convert?

Comment: I am not sure if I have understood you properly.

Comment: I have. You're getting a number format exception, which is being caused by `this` not having a proper field set in Integer, but rather in Hex.

Comment: In my ItemVO, i have not set anything as Hex but everthing is either String or Double.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I'd say its the `Id` field thats being autogenerated since you have an `@Id` annotation there and they type of that field needs to be something other than `Long`.

Just glossing over the morphia documentation, it looks like you have to have the Id field defined as type ObjectId if you want Mongo to autogenerate it or else you have to set it yourself.

http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/EntityAnnotation

Comment: yes it is defined at ObjectId but what about NumberFormatException?

Comment: @Rachel -- Modify your ItemVO object to use ObjectId as the field type of the id member variable instead of Long.

Comment: You mean you cannot compile it if you use ObjectId?

Comment: yes that is correct, now my vo class is extending base class which has following annotations, Id
 JsonIgnore
 EqualsInclude
 protected ObjectId _id;

Comment: ok. if its already in base class and base class compiles, then I dont see what the problem is. you could get rid of id altogether. or else you could do an explicit import 
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

Comment: it is still throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

As the id is auto generated  either the id field should be set with some number or change the data type to string.